# Расположение div внутри table-cell по центру вертикально и горизонтально

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок div с классом .center-please который необходимо расположить по центру вертикально и горизонтально. Если в .b-item впишу просто текст, то он строго по центру.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.b-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(1),
.b-item:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 200px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-please {
  // Как расположить div по центру?

}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-item">
    200px
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    100% - 400px
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <div class='center-please'>
      <button>Кнопка 1</button>
      <br>
      <button>Кнопка 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Точно также, как вы сделали для второго `.b-item`.

Comment: Но выравнивает он только по горизонтали, а не вертикали

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде `vertical-align: middle;` стоял только для 2 блока.

Кроме того, извращение с удалением границ среднего блока - лишнее. Надо всей таблице поставить `border-collapse: collapse;`

Таблица и ячейки должны иметь `float:none;` В примере это не важно, но на реальной странице нужно, если свойство `float` будет унаследовано.

Кнопки по `<br>` будут смещены относительно друг друга. Поэтому `<br>` удален, а кнопкам задан класс `.btn {display: block; margin: auto;}`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
  display: table;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.b-item {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(1),
.b-item:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 200px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(3) {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-please {
  // Как расположить div по центру?

}
button.btn {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-item">
    200px
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    100% - 400px
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <div class='center-please'>
      <button class="btn">Кнопка 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Кнопка 2</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой вариант:

```
.center-please {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

если я конечно вас правильно понял)